Django Hot Reload
I am running docker image of a Django application with an entrypoint like this:
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
In settings.py DEBUG=True.
However StatReloader doesn't seem to boot up (no logs regarding it's existence) to watch for module/.py file changes.
Also there is mount configured so that the docker is aware of host changes and I have double checked it using docker exec.
When I do the first edit in the file I get this sort of log:
project  | Performing system checks...
project  |
project  | April 24, 2024 - 17:11:15
project  | Django version 4.2.4, using settings 'project.settings'
project  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
project  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Afterwards nothing happens and nothing changes, it seems like it's stuck calling that reload from StatReloader.

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  In general, Docker's core model is that the container filesystem is isolated from the host system; can you use a plain Python virtual environment, without Docker involved, for this sort of development task?

I am not able to use it since we're using google cloud and the setting up of the environment for app engine to work would take quite significant effort for each new person that should start working on it.

@AleksaBajat can you share your settings.py and Dockerfile?
